# Cryptographically secure XML comparator

Tags: c#, .net, xml, cryptography

I need to compare two XMLs, which I get in the form of `string`s.  I can't just compare the strings, because that fails when attributes are listed in a different order, which I don't want to consider a difference with regards to the XMLs.

There exists several libraries for this problem as described, but I have additional constraints regarding security.  Since the XML is customer data, our company security policy demands that all functions operating on the data are cryptographically secure.

So I guess what I need is a cryptographically secure XML comparator, which I can't seem to find anywhere.  Can anyone please point me towards either a library or code sample, preferably in C#.Net, I can use or at least look at?  Whether the cryptography is in the form of SSL, AES, CAST5 or whatever is not important as long as it is established and proven.

Comment: Cryptographic security doesn't mean anything in the context of comparison functions. It's something that would only be of interest when talking with hashing, encryption/decryption, signing, or random number generation functions, usually

Comment: @bdonlan I guess I can't argue with that, but we have a very strict code policy that I have to follow.  (I'm in banking)

Comment: Reread your company policy. If it really says that, tell the people in charge to be a tad more specific. There ain't no such thing as cryptographically secure comparisons! Do you use 'cryptographically secure addition' to balance accounts...? ;-)

Comment: On the other hand, there are such things as cryptographically _insecure_ comparisons... http://rdist.root.org/2008/03/25/wii-hacking-and-the-freeloader/

Comment: @Pontus It really says that; I've been on this problem for a week now before asking for help.  Regarding "more specific", I've basically been told that "just about any decent security" will suffice.

Comment: You say that string comparison is out of the question due to attribute ordering (which is of course correct with respect to XML standards). Assuming this was not an issue, how exactly do you perform "cryptographically secure" string comparisons, then?

Comment: @Jonas I (obviously) can't give out the details, but we do have libraries for secure string comparisons.  Maybe if I just split the XML into series of strings and use the existing code to compare those?

Comment: Basically, the premise of the question is nonsense and the poster won't accept this fact.

Comment: @CSpangled: Could you give an example of *how* those libraries perform "secure string comparisons"? What are they doing that makes them secure?

Comment: @Adam: I'm not allowed to post our security implementations on the internet.  Sorry.

Comment: @CSpangled: If you can't post details, then there's nothing we can do to help you, since your question doesn't make sense without more context. "Cryptographically secure comparison" doesn't have any meaning in itself. No need to apologize though; it's not our problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the XML to [Canonical XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-c14n) or [Exclusive Canonical XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-exc-c14n/) and perform a binary comparison. These canonicalization algorithms are used in XML-DSIG, so they should qualify as "cryptographically secure".

You can use something like this:

```
  XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
  doc.LoadXml(xml);
  System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.Transform t = new System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.XmlDsigC14NTransform();
  // or System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.XmlDsigExcC14NTransform
  t.Resolver = null;
  t.LoadInput(doc);
  Stream stream = (Stream)t.GetOutput(typeof(Stream));
  string canonicalXml = new StreamReader(stream).ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this will suffice.  Thanks!

Comment: @CSpangled: You should realize that this isn't actually "secure" in any meaningful sense. The only relation it has to security is that it's part of a signature specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-c14n

Comment: It canonicalizes the XML so @CSpangled can use his secret secure string comparator to solve the rest of the problem. So assuming the PHB who wrote the security policy wants secure string comparisons, this does "solve" the problem :-)

Comment: @Will:  The poster works for a bank.  His code doesn't have to be secure.  It just has to appear as if it is secure.  Another "benefit" from Sarbanes-Oxley.

Comment: @Gilbert: Fair point. This code at least has the `System.Security.Cryptography` namespace in it, so I guess that's sufficient :)